# postMessage to all iframes on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want to send postMessage to all iframes on the page with a given class. I can make use of jQuery (need not be vanilla javascript solution).

Html:

when i tried something like:

```
var allIframes = $(".givenClass iframe");

allIframes[0].contentWindow //undefined
```

How do we get the contentWindow for the iframe using jQuery?

Comment: Have you wrapped the code with `$(document).ready()`? Also, what browser are you on? some replace `contentWindow` with `contentDocument`..

Comment: You say that the iframes have the class, but you select children of that class, do you mean to write `$("iframe.givenClass")`?

Comment: Do you get any frames at all? What is the `allIframes.length`? Are your frames contained within an element with `.givenClass` or the class is applied to the frames?

Comment: My html is: <div class="givenClass"> <iframe src="..."></iframe> </div>
I'm using $(document).ready()
allIframes.length is showing fine (>0)

Comment: I'm using chrome but i need a cross browser solution.

Comment: if all the pages are on the same domain, you can use localStorage to raise a storage event on all iframes at once...